# How I can control the Debug window of the MobileVRInterface in Godot with a mouse?

Tags: ios, ubuntu, augmented-reality, virtual-reality, godot

So I've an iPhone and I'm developing a VR application on Ubuntu using Godot's MobileVRInterface. When I run the application, I'm not able to control the debug window using mouse which is an expected behavior but for rapid development, instead of exporting the application for iOS everytime, is there a way to control this Debug window using Mouse?

[debug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/orX4E.png)

The other option that I'm thinking: I've a cardboard, it'd be great, if I can directly stream the gyroscopic information to Godot to my Ubuntu machine from the iPhone and use the cardboard to experience what I'm building.

Basically, I'm trying to use Google Cardboard on iOS with Godot on Ubuntu while developing the VR application, if that's too complicated; I'm thinking of using a simpler solution i.e to use the mouse as a virtual VR device so that I can control the debug window.